# $\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x}{x^6+i}$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{-a}^{a}{\frac{x}{x^6+i}}\,dx$$ where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit.

Let $f(x):=\frac{x}{x^6+i}$. Then $f(-x)=\frac{-x}{(-x)^6+i}=\frac{-x}{x^6+i}=-f(x)$. Therefore $f$ is odd and the integral equals zero $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: What is $x$ ? Is it a real variable or a complex variable ? What about $a$ ?

Comment: both $x$ and $a$ are real

Comment: I think the result is zero

Comment: I think what you have said is true for all x

Comment: Yes, what you have is correct.